# Imprimir los valores en cada barra, en matplotlib, ayuda por favor

Tags: python, matplotlib

Por mas que busco en la web, no logro encontrar como hacer que me aparezcan los valores de cada barra, justo en su parte superior. 
Necesito hacer que el porcentaje que representa cada una, se imprima justo hacia la parte superior.

Aquí un trozo del código que genera el código:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))

n = 1  # This is our first dataset (out of 2)
t = 3 # Number of datasets
d = 6 # Number of sets of bars
w = 0.8 # Width of each bar
very = [t*element + w*n for element
             in range(d)]
plt.bar(very, dfsusort['Very interested'], color = '#5cb85c')

n = 2  
t = 3 
d = 6 
w = 0.8 
some = [t*element + w*n for element
             in range(d)]
plt.bar(some, dfsusort['Somewhat interested'], color = '#5bc0de')

n = 3  
t = 3 
d = 6 
w = 0.8 
notin = [t*element + w*n for element
             in range(d)]
plt.bar(notin, dfsusort['Not interested'], color = '#d9534f')


for index, value in enumerate(dfsusort['Very interested'], 0): 
    label = format(float(value), ',')

    plt.annotate(label, xy=(value - 0.5, index - 0.08), color='black', size=14)

for index, value in enumerate(dfsusort['Somewhat interested'], 0): 
    label = format(float(value), ',')

    plt.annotate(label, xy=(value - 0.5, index - 0.08), color='black', size=14)

for index, value in enumerate(dfsusort['Not interested'], 0): 
    label = format(float(value), ',')

   plt.annotate(label, xy=(value - 0.5, index - 0.08), color='black', size=14)


plt.title('Percentage of Respondent`s Interest in Data Science Areas', size=16)
plt.legend(labels=dfsusort.columns, loc='upper right', prop={'size': 14})
ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(dfsusort.index, rotation=90, size=14)
bx = plt.axes()
bx.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
bx.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
bx.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

plt.show
```

Adjunto imagen tambien de mi resultado, donde falta efectivamente los valores de cada barra en la parte superior que es en donde quiero quye se visibilizen

[image: preferencias de data science survey]

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta. ¿Quieres poner el valor (% en este caso) en la parte superior, dentro o fuera de la barra? ¿Podrías poner tu código completo, particularmente el `dfsusort[]`?

Comment: La respuesta corta: tienes que usar `text`, de hecho intenta cambiar el `annotate` que es _overkill_ para esto y usa `text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr este gráfico

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe un método `text` para los ejes... personalmente uso `plt` directamente para todos los gráfico y llamo los ejes con

```
ax = plt.gca()
```

Aquí la implementación

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

# Se crea un dataset "df" aunque el OP emplea "dfsuort"
months = ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'abr', 'may', 'jun']
Very_interested = 100*np.random.random(6)
Somewhat_interested = 40*np.random.random(6)
Not_interested = 5*np.random.random(6)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Months': months,
    'Very interested': Very_interested,
    'Somewhat interested': Somewhat_interested,
    'Not interested': Not_interested
})
print(df)

columns = df.columns.tolist()[1:] # no se incluye meses
colors = ['#5cb85c', '#5bc0de', '#d9534f']
barWidth = 0.25

br1 = np.arange(df.shape[0]) - barWidth
br2 = br1 + barWidth
br3 = br2 + barWidth
brs = [br1, br2, br3]
print(br1)


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

for br, color, col_name in zip(brs, colors, columns):
    print(br, col_name)
    plt.bar(br, df[col_name], width=barWidth, color=color, label=col_name)

plt.xticks(br2, months)

ax = plt.gca()
for br, color, col_name in zip(brs, colors, columns):
    for j, v in enumerate(df[col_name].values):
        ax.text(br[j]-barWidth*0.5, v+1, f"{v:,.2f}", color=color, fontweight='bold', fontsize=8)

plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

Honestamente la pregunta inicial no tiene datos, por tanto cuando se ejecute este código al trabajarse con números aleatorios se obtendrá un gráfico diferente pero manteniendo el formato y lo que se pide